# Call flow of recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.io.*;
class combination
{
    static int cntr =  0;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        combination call = new combination();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
        String n = br.readLine();
        call.comb("",n);
        System.out.println("Number of combinations are : "+cntr);
    }
    public void comb(String beg, String end) throws IOException
    {
        if (end.length()<=1)
        {
            cntr++;
            System.out.println(beg+end);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=0;i<end.length();i++)
            {
                String n = end.substring(0,i)+end.substring(i+1);
                comb(beg + end.charAt(i),n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above program gives the combination of a particular string.

I am unable to understand call flow of the recursion. I want to know the call flow of the above recursive program.

Can any one explain this?

Comment: Well what about it don't you understand? Have you tried stepping through it? Do you understand recursion in general?

Comment: When a method calls itself inside its body, that's _Recursion_. What else you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Your program does all permutations, not all combinations. There are n! (n factorial of them) as well as the program makes n! calls. Recursion represents a stack of method-calls. Bear in mind that each recursion-step corresponds to each stack entry. Each stack entry keeps its local variables. Now let's go over the flow step by step. As an example let n="abc". length=3 --> !n=1*2*3=6 recursion calls. Recursion ends when var end.length <= 1. It's **a base case** (System.out.println). On each base case we go 1 level back in the recursion tree.

So the flow is (usually it's called a **recursion tree**):

```
Step 1. Recurse
  Step 2  Recurse
    Step 3 Base case --> print abc
  Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
  Step 4
    Step 5 Base case --> print acb
  Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
Step 6. Recurse
  Step 7  Recurse
    Step 8 Base case --> print bac
  Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
  Step 9  Recurse
    Step 10 Base case --> print bca
  Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
Step 11. Recurse
  Step 12  Recurse
    Step 13 Base case --> print cab
  Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
  Step 14  Recurse
    Step 15 Base case --> print cba
  Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
Go 1 level back on the recursion tree
end.
```

From this flow you can imagine "Recursion step" as a push operation and "Go 1 level back" as a pop operation on a stack and go through the flow/code.

Here's a detailed analysis of calls, you can do it by debugging to understand or on a piece of parer.

```
        Step 1: Recursion Level 1
          beg = ""
          end = "abc"
          cntr = 0
          i = 0
          n="bc"

          Step 2: Recursion Level 2
            beg = "a"
            end = "bc"
            cntr = 0
            i = 0
            n = "c"

            Step 3: Recursion Level 3
            beg = "ab"
            end = "c", It's a base case --> Print beg+end = abc
            cntr = 0
            i = 0
          Go back to Recursion level 2

          Step 4: Recursion Level 2
          beg = "a"
          end = "bc"
          cntr = 1
          i = 1  Print beg+end = acb
            cntr = 1
          Go back to Recursion level 2
        Go back to Recursion level 1

        Step 6: Recursion Level 1
        beg = ""
        end = "abc"
        cntr = 1
        i = 1
        n = "ac"

          Step 7: Recursion Level 2
          beg = "b"
          end = "ac"
          cntr = 2
          i = 0
          n = "c"

            Step 8: Recursion Level 3
            beg = "ba"
            end = "c", It's a base case --> Print beg+end = bac
            cntr = 2
            i = 0
            n = "c"
          Go back to Recursion level 2

          Step 9: Recursion Level 2
          beg = "b"
          end = "ac"
          cntr = 3
          i = 1
          n = "a"

            Step 10: Recursion Level 3
            beg = "bc"
            end = "a", It's a base case --> Print beg+end = bca
            cntr = 3
            i = 1
            n = "c"
          Go back to Recursion level 2
        Go back to Recursion level 1

        Step 11: Recursion Level 1
          beg = ""
          end = "abc"
          cntr = 4
          i = 2
          n="ab"

          Step 12: Recursion Level 2
            beg = "c"
            end = "ab"
            cntr = 4
            i = 0
            n = "b"

            Step 13: Recursion Level 3
            beg = "ca"
            end = "b", It's a base case --> Print beg+end = cab
            cntr = 0
            i = 0
          Go back to Recursion level 2

          Step 14: Recursion Level 2
            beg = "c"
            end = "ab"
            cntr = 5
            i = 1
            n = "a"

            Step 15: Recursion Level 3
            beg = "cb"
            end = "a", It's a base case --> Print beg+end = cba
            cntr = 6
            i = 1
          Go back to Recursion level 2
        Go back to Recursion level 1
      end.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `comb` takes a string and shows all of the ways that the characters in that string can be rearranged. For example, if you input `"abc"`, the program will give the following output:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
Number of combinations are : 6
```

Part of the problem here is that `comb`'s names aren't very clear about what's going on. If I were maintaining this code, I would rename `beg` to `combinedChars` and `end` to `uncombinedChars` (or maybe `remainingChars`), because the function works by moving a single character from `end` to `beg` at each level of recursion. The algorithm is basically:

- Is there only one character left to be combined?

  - If so, there's only one way to combine it with the characters that have already been shuffled around, so combine it, print the result, and update the count.
  - If not, go through the list of characters that haven't been combined yet. Take each one in turn as the next character in the combination, then repeat the process with the remaining uncombined characters until only one remains.